# Fragment onSaveInstanceState not being called

Tags: android, fragment

I am experimenting with using fragments in my application.  I am trying to find a way to store  data used by a fragment when I switch my application to the other fragment.  My code for my second fragment is found below.  When switching to and from this fragment I am using add and remove fragment.  This is because when I was using replace, I was having trouble.  Whenever I switch to my other fragment, and back to this one, count is not stored.  How do I actually store count so I can come back to it when my fragment opens back up?

```
public class BasicFragment2 extends Fragment {

public int count = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        count = savedInstanceState.getInt("Integer");
    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_basic_2, container, false);

    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    // A simple OnClickListener for our button. You can see here how a Fragment can encapsulate
    // logic and views to build out re-usable Activity components.
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Activity activity = getActivity();
            count++;

            if (activity != null) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "This is not a fragment...Yes it is " + count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });

    return view;
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    outState.putInt("Integer",count);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try overriding `onSaveInstanceState` in your `Activity` class and save the count value there. Because as per google docs:

> Note however: this method may be called at any time before
>   onDestroy(). There are many situations where a fragment may be mostly
>   torn down (such as when placed on the back stack with no UI showing),
>   but its state will not be saved until its owning activity actually
>   needs to save its state.

Comment: What exactly would be the best way to pass this data to my activity though?  Should I create two methods in my fragment to pass the data back and forth with the activity?  Or is there a way I could use like a global variable.

Comment: define public methods in your fragment (for e.g. `getCount`/`setCount`), then get a reference of your fragment in activity and call the defined methods to get or set the count value in your fragment